# Removal of SerializesModels on Queued Event Listeners does not take effect when mocking on unit tests

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-events

I'm currently working with Laravel's Queued Event Listeners on an Eloquent model's `saving` event. On my event class, I have set up a public property that contains my model which I can then access inside the `$event` object within my listener via `$event->myModel`.

The `handle()` method on my listener compares old values from the new one so I removed `Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels` on my event class. This works fine and I'm now able to compare old values from the new one.

The issue is with testing.
I am making a test that checks if the old and new value that I'm getting inside my listener's `handle()` method is different. However, the `$event->myModel->getOriginal()` now returns an empty array. This only happens when testing.

Is this a bug?

I tried setting a `public $originalModelProps` on my event class however, it returns empty when the handle() method on my listener is called.

I'm not using `Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels` or any trait/class/interface named `SerializesModels` on my code.

**Events/Models/MyModel/MyModelSavedEvent.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Events\Models\MyModel;

use App\Models\MyModel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class MyModelSavedEvent
{
    /**
     *
     * @var \App\Models\MyModel
     */
    public $myModel;

    public $originalAccessLevelProps;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     * 
     * @param \App\Models\MyModel
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(MyModel $myModel)
    {
        $this->myModel = $myModel;
        $this->originalAccessLevelProps = $this->myModel->getOriginal('level');
    }
}
```

**Listeners/Models/MyModel/MyModelSavedEventListener.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Listeners\Models\MyModel;

use Log;
use App\Models\MyModel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use App\Events\Models\MyModel\MyModelSavedEvent;

class MyModelSavedEventListener implements ShouldQueue
{
    /**
     * The queue connection that should handle the job.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $connection = 'sqs';

    /**
     * The number of times the job may be attempted.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $tries = 3;

    /**
     * The number of seconds the job can run before timing out.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $timeout = 60;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // ..
    }

    /**
     * This job should only be queued if the level of myModel
     * has been updated.
     *
     * @param  \App\Events\Models\MyModel\MyModelSavedEvent $event
     * 
     * @return bool
     */
    public function shouldQueue(MyModelSavedEvent $event)
    {
        $prevLevel = $event->myModel->getOriginal('level');
        $currLevel = $event->myModel->level;

        return $prevLevel !== $currLevel;
    }

    public function handle(MyModelSavedEvent $event): void
    {
        $prevLevel = $event->myModel->getOriginal('level');
        $currLevel = $event->myModel->level;

        Log::info([
            'Running handle!',
            $event->myModel->getOriginal(), // This returns an empty array
            $event->originalAccessLevelProps, // This is null
            $event->myModel->id, // This returns a string
            $prevLevel, // This returns null
            $currLevel // This contains the latest value
        ]);

        // ..
    }
}
```

**tests/app/Listeners/Models/MyModel/MyModelSavedEventListener.php**

```php
<?php

public function testSample()
{
    Queue::fake();

    $myModel = MyModel::where(...)->first();

    Queue::assertNothingPushed();

    // This will trigger the event
    $myModel->level = 'new level';
    $myModel->save();

    Queue::assertPushedOn('sqs', MyModelSavedEventListener::class);
}
```

I was expecting that similar to how it works outside of the test, I'll be able to compare old and new values.

**Edit:**
The event is triggered via MyModel's `$dispatchesEvents` property:

```php
/**
 * The event map for the model.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'saved' => \App\Events\Models\MyModel\MyModelSavedEvent::class,
];
```

**Update**: Found out that my model is indeed not being serialized. Its just that `getOriginal()` is still returning an empty array when called within the listener's `handle()` method

Comment: How is the event being triggered?

Comment: Note that the event listener used in your test class has the same name as the test class itself `MyModelSavedEventListener`

Comment: Hi @miken32, I updated the question. The event is being triggered via MyModel's $dispatchesEvents property

Comment: @CaddyDZ, i might have mixed the class names but only because I had to rename them for a bit of privacy :) Got no issues with the names, everything's firing fine, just the serialization.

Answer (score 0):

`SerializesModel` is used to save space by serializing the model ID and some meta information when storing the job in the queue.

When you pass a model instance to a job that does not use `SerializesModel` the instance is still serialized with PHP's `serialize()` and restored when the listener gets called.

So maybe try to pass your properties of interest directly to `MyModelSavedEvent::dispatch()`

Comment: Hi @timw, how should I do this via queued event listeners? The model is firing the event manually via MyModel's $dispatchesEvents property

Comment: @Dreadnaut you can fire another event from the models listener and queue only the subsequent event. Then you can pass any properties you like. I also had some problems with queued model listeners.

For example `MyModelCompareOriginal::dispatch($old, $original)`.